# Cannot change default language in MS Word

Tags: microsoft-word, language, microsoft-word-2016

I have tried many way but Word just refuse to change its default proofing language. This is the screen shot.
As you can see,

- the Normal style was selected.
- the language in Normal Style is Vietnamese.
- but the language in the bottom bar say English. As the number of words is 0, you can clearly see this is a newly opened document, no changes were made at all.

I have tried

- change proofing language in general (in Options, as in the 2nd image)
- change proofing language in normal style
- change proofing language in normal.dotm
- turn off automatically language detecting everywhere and anywhere I see it (Review tab, Style, Normal.dotm).

What can I do to make sure the default proofing language is something I want?
The versions are Office Professional 2016 plus and Win 10.
[image: Languages in Word]
[image]

Comment: The second image show your editing language is Vietnamese as default. If you choose English (United State), would the "Set as Default" be clickable?

Comment: Yes, it would. Selecting any language not set as default would make the button "Select as default" clickable.

Comment: Please check whether the reply for your issue on Q&A forum is helpful. "[Changing default proofing languague in Word not possible?](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/456010/changing-default-proofing-languague-in-word-not-po.html)".

Comment: @Emily: the reply works, thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

To those whose Microsoft Word refuses to change the proofing language, and even tries the solutions provided by Microsoft:

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/can-not-change-proofing-language/b2fbdec9-2043-4fed-a72f-752c6b56385e

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/cant-change-proofing-language/db1056e8-eb1c-49ad-825e-1cf40b4e6261

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/proofing-language-wont-change/ce9ee43b-a5f3-494e-b02c-3a64278d1bc8

but the proofing language remains unchanged. Here is my solution:

0. Backup your file so that if you mess up, you can start over again.
1. When Microsoft Word is closed, open the problematic document by 7-Zip or another archive file manager.
2. In 7-Zip, right click \word\styles.xml and select Edit.
3. You might see some <w:lang w:val="en-US" ...>. This means the language in the current document is set to "English (United States)" as in the [ISO 639-1 standard language codes](https://www.andiamo.co.uk/resources/iso-language-codes/).
4. Change "en-US" to the language you want to set as default. For example, if you want to change to "Chinese (Taiwan)", then change it to "zh-tw".
5. Make sure the new language is saved in the archived docx file. Close 7-Zip, and open the docx file in Microsoft Word. You might find the language of your document is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

See [my article on the Microsoft Answers site](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/proofing-language-keeps-changing-solutions-how-can/c6483d0c-6fe3-41bf-8464-25535d3ec15b).

Basic advice:

**First**, if your keyboard is set to a different language, change it to the language you want to be using.

**Second**, if possible, your Operating System (Windows/MacOS) regional language settings should match your primary language setting in Word.

**Third**: Become familiar with the Proofing Language as a concept and with the Proofing Language Dialog

The "*proofing language*" is a key to several Word features including spelling and grammar and AutoCorrect. It is not an application-wide setting nor even a document setting; it is set at the character level! It is set at the character level in every document.

**Status Bar** (This  part about the Status Bar may only apply to Windows versions.)

You can display the proofing language for a particular place in a document on the Status Bar. (Windows) If this is not showing there, right-click and add it.
[image: picture of status bar with language enabled]
Right-clicking on the Status Bar lets you check or uncheck what you want there.
[image: screenshot customizing status bar]

**Fourth**, make sure that you turn off the proofing option to detect language automatically. Word is bad at this and terrible when it comes to distinguishing the spelling in various forms of English (or other languages with multiple spelling versions).

There are two checkboxes at the bottom of the proofing language dialog. Both should be blank (empty). On this dialog, the settings for what the proofing language is and for checking spelling are grammar are at the character level. On the other hand, the setting for detecting language automatically is a system setting that applies to all documents that you open until it is changed.

**Fifth**, you can apply language settings to particular text using a character style with that language setting. (You can do paragraph styles as well.) Such a style can be applied using a keyboard shortcut. When you want to turn it off, press **Ctrl+Spacebar** to return to the underlying language in the paragraph style. Here are my instructions on [assigning a keyboard shortcut to a style](http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/styles.htm#Keyboard).

**Sixth**, remember that language characteristics are at the character level. They can be carried into a document with pasted text.

**Seventh**, if you have your document set to update styles from the template upon opening, this may be turning some things off.

**Eighth**, if you still have the problem, a workaround is to start typing, then select your text, and apply a style with the language setting you need.

Comment: Zeroth, thank you very much for the detailed answer.
First, Word is an infrequently used App (in my work flow), I would rather not change system-wise setting for it.
Second, fourth, fifth: nice to know.
Third: done, done, and done. Before posting question.
Sixth: how do I know if styles are update upon opening?

Comment: Oh, I found the check box, it's not checked.

Comment: Step 7 is not a solution to change default proofing language. As soon as you type any text anywhere, the new text will be in the default language.

Comment: Step 7 is a workaround required because of your decision to not implement Step 1. Did you use the macros?

Comment: The solution was changing the language of keyboard. It takes just one key combination. As I stated, step 7 is not a solution, even if it's implemented. That step only affects existing text. The intention of changing default language is to affect future text. I know that was not stated, and I am sorry for the trouble.